# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target on endpoints connection in corporate network only

Tags: java, spring, maven, ssl, java-security

I am getting the below exception in corporate network only while trying to connect an endpoint https://nodeA1.test.webservices.amadeus.com.

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.tsal.grms.booking.ws.common.client.WSClient.sendAndReceive(WSClient.java:72) [com-tsal-grms-booking-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.booking.altea.AlteaWSClient.sendAndReceive(AlteaWSClient.java:46) [com-tsal-grms-booking-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.booking.altea.serivices.SecurityAuthenticateWS.acquireSession(SecurityAuthenticateWS.java:77) [com-tsal-grms-booking-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.booking.altea.serivices.SecurityAuthenticateWS.acquireSession(SecurityAuthenticateWS.java:127) [com-tsal-grms-booking-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.booking.altea.AmadeusAlteaWSImpl.securityAuthenticate(AmadeusAlteaWSImpl.java:135) [com-tsal-grms-booking-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.booking.altea.AmadeusAlteaWSCoreImpl.getSeatAvaliability(AmadeusAlteaWSCoreImpl.java:69) [com-tsal-grms-booking-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.booking.client.BookingClientImpl.getSeatAvaliability(BookingClientImpl.java:31) [com-tsal-grms-booking-client-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.core.requestmanagement.RequestCoherenceCoreImpl.checkSeatAvailabilityForRequest(RequestCoherenceCoreImpl.java:350) [com-tsal-grms-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.tsal.grms.core.requestmanagement.RequestCoherenceCoreImpl.enforceRequestCoherence(RequestCoherenceCoreImpl.java:81) [com-tsal-grms-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection.getRequestOutputStream(HttpUrlConnection.java:85) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractSenderConnection$RequestTransportOutputStream.createOutputStream(AbstractSenderConnection.java:106) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.TransportOutputStream.getOutputStream(TransportOutputStream.java:41) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.TransportOutputStream.write(TransportOutputStream.java:64) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.writeTo(MessageImpl.java:1314) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.writeTo(SaajSoapMessage.java:275) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:46) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:654) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:603) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
```

I have added the certificate also in keystore.
[image]

Kindly advice to resolve the issue as its been there from long time.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the keystore you mentioned is being used by the java process? You can also enable `-Djavax.net.debug=all` JVM option to see what's happening.

Comment: I enabled and found some errors in the logs. Not sure with what it is related to. Pasting that errors part here.

%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown

%% Invalidated:  [Session-3, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown

Comment: I think what @zaerymoghaddam is referring to is right the top of the debugging output. It should read something like: `trustStore is: <path to your truststore>
trustStore type is: pkcs12` If that path doesn't point to the same store where you have put your proxy's certificate(s), then that's where the problem lies.

Comment: @Daniel I have added the certificates to the path which you mentioned how to get it. Now it is working. Thanks :)

Comment: What version of Java were you running ? I mean which exact version, like 1.8.0_241-b07.

Comment: Version - 1.8.0_212